# Access files from linux home folder

Tags: php, linux

I have images located in linux home directory. I have to access those images and show to user.

when i tried to include location like this in css file

```
background: url('/home/images/imagename.jpg');
```

it is looking in the htdocs /usr/local/apache/htdocs/home/images/imagename.jpg.

and, also i have tried to load the xml from home folder it is also doing same thing

```
$test = file_get_contents ( '/home/test/test.xml' );
```

Please suggest me how can i achieve this.

because i have different folders in home directory which consists images amd xml files.  i wrote logic to show images from different folders, but i am unable access from home.

Comment: I am thinking to copy the required folder from home to htdocs. But its lengthy process and wasting memory.

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS file, the path is from the "URL_ROOT" which is something like thate : http://www.myurl.tld/

In `file_get_contents` the path is from "file_system", but Apache do'nt have access right to the "HOME".

You must put the IMAGES/XML, you want to display to the user, in a directory accessible and readable by Apache ; like the "htDocs" :`/var/www/`

Answer (score 0):

for the `file_get_contents`;

If you set `open_basedir` or `include_path` in your php.ini (or as `php_flag` directive in apache config) to `/home/images` or `/home/test/` (whichever you're using) then this should help.

In addition, you may need to give the `www-data` or `apache` user permissions.

For the CSS declaration, you can only access files above the root of your domain.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$file = file_get_contents('./imagename.jpg', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
```

in your php.ini file make this setting

```
include_path=".:/home/images"
```

or use this function at runtime

```
set_include_path()  for same
```